# Unable to maintain stable connection from 10.10.4 using a reverse proxy

Tags: macos, network, webserver

I've got a server running OS X 10.10.4 and it's giving me some trouble. I have several applications sitting behind a reverse proxy, and for a while, everything worked great. I've got port forwarding turned on in my router, and a domain pointed at my IP so that I can access this server and the applications from outside, all over port 80.

The problem is that suddenly these applications are unresponsive and I get connection timeouts when I try to hit anything, either directly or over http.

The weird part is how to make the server respond again. I found that if I ssh'd into the server, just the act of doing that login got apache (2.4) to respond to requests again. After I logout and the server sits around for about 10 minutes, it stops responding again. A new login refreshes it and the server starts to respond. I can repeat this process over and over.

Some things I've done:

Turned off the blue tooth modem feature

Made sure wifi was turned off completely, as this is a wired connection

Turned off all other networking interfaces but the wired connection to prevent potential conflicts.

Restarted the machine

If there is any information you need, or configs to see, I will be more than happy to provide. Everything was working just fine up until yesterday.

Here is a vhost for the main site, and one of the reverse proxy applications. This is all running under Apache 2.4

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerAdmin mike@thecommissioncafe.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/lain/Sites/public"
    ServerName thecommissioncafe.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/cafe-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/cafe-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName coffeebean.thecommissioncafe.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off

        <Proxy *>
                Require all granted
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.201:9000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.201:9000/

        <Location />
                Require all granted
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I've taken a stab to remove the [meta] from the post. We have detailed guidance on [ask] if you don't get an answer. My guess is everyone will make guesses and try to help you with troubleshooting steps like "run `tcpdump` to look at the most important piece of traffic and start there... Also, some detail on how you set up your reverse proxy (and what specific software it's running) might help someone catch a configuration mistake.

Comment: [Don't cross-post your questions.](http://serverfault.com/questions/725041/unable-to-maintain-stable-connection-to-os-x-server) If you wish to move your question somewhere else, you should flag for moderator attention.